# Redirect user to a personal page based on User Id

Tags: wordpress, authentication

Hi I use this code to redirect users on login based on the user role.

I want to modify it to use redirect based on the user id.

How could i do this?
Thanks

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
    if( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ) {
        $url = home_url('mypage.html');
        } else {
            $url = home_url('/index.php');
            }
            }
            return $url;}add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$user` object already contains the `ID`.

Your code would then look like this if you want to check for user with id `79`:

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if ( $user->ID == 79 ) {
            $url = home_url( '/mypage.html' );
        } else {
            $url = home_url( '/index.php' );
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Put the above in your `functions.php`. Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added your code and changed the id to 79 (the user i want) but it redirects me to the else condition ('/index.php')

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work. It executes the else condition.

Comment: I've updated the code. Put it in your functions.php, tested and works.